# onStart of new Activity is called before onStop of parent

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, lifecycle, robospice

I've got an application. I use `startActivity()` to start activity.

Can anyone actually tell me why system is calling `onStart()` of new Activity first, instead of parents `onStop()`? Is that even possible (without system bug)?

I've found [Fragment onStop() being called directly after onStart() - WHY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581986/fragment-onstop-being-called-directly-after-onstart-why) answer, but I got nothing in common with Fragments and using android-support library. I'm stuck because I'm using RoboSpice and it must contain proper, synchronized methods in onStart and onStop. I can't because system is calling it in wrong order.

I'm using GCM and Analytics libraries as well in this application.

Comment: are you using tabgroupActivity?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you have a read of the [Activity Lifecycle documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) onStop is only called when the current activity is replaced by a new (or previous) one.

For that to happen the other application has to start or resume... otherwise there would be a gap

onPause of the current activity is (I would expect) called before the onStart of the replacing Activity

Comment: Now I see, reading documentation for a 2nd, 3rd (and so on) time can always bring something new to knowledge. `onStop()` is "called when the activity is no longer visible to the user, because another activity **has been resumed**"

Comment: It took me quite a while to spot that onPause could be more useful than onStop too :)

Comment: Yes, playing between `onPause()` and `onStop()` may end up in funny ways.
I know that putting RoboSpice's `start()` and `shouldStop()` to `onResume()` and `onPause()` may not be a great idea, but it's only way (for now) to have only one instance of RoboManager shared between Activities. (for a future answers)

Comment: Also, in the documentation of the onPause() function, they say: "After receiving this call (ndlr "onPause()") you will usually receive a following call to onStop() (after the next activity has been resumed and displayed)".